# Access routes in ruby after logged in

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have routes in `routes.rb` like: `get 'users/edit/:id'`. I made a login route as well.

I want to check if someone is logged in before he accesses a route, so if we try to access `get 'users/edit/:id'` without logged in we will redirect to the login screen.

How can I do that? I think I should write something after the routes to check if the user is logged in, but I don't know the syntax.
Thx for the answers

Comment: It is a quite broad question. Do you use `devise` or a similar gem? How did you implement user authentication? Please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This can be done at the controller level. You can add something called a before_filter to your edit action in the users/edit controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_login, only: [:edit]

  def edit
    # your code here
  end
end
```

You can also use many authentication gems (e.g. devise). Check devise out here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise

It allows you to write code like this:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    # your code here
  end

end
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: If you take the first approach (and not use devise), then `require_login` should be defined in `ApplicationController` and typically check a cookie for authentication info (and most commonly assign the corresponding user instance to `@current_user`). If there no valid cookie, then you can redirect to login. When you redirect you should pass along your current path so that you can redirect back to it after a successful sign in.